# how to get the features from Geoserver using REST

Tags: java, rest, openlayers, geoserver

I have installed Geoserver on my local system. And i am accessing the layers using WFS in OpenLayers, to Show the data.

But i need to add the data(features) from the Java code using REST.

where can i get information on those..

Help me on how to proceed further to save my geospatial data into Geoserver from Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Geoserver we do not have option modify the layer data using REST API.

we have only to create the layers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look into WFT-T.

Check these links:

- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html
- http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html
- http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/vector_data/index.html

Simone.

Comment: But I want to add data using rest not from the map.. Because I have existing data so need to put using background task.. just a java code to push data.. directly to geoserver

Comment: Then you might want to look into GeoTools. I would suggesting sending an email to the GeoTools mailing list.

Comment: You can find additional examples here:
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/rest.html